# Reformat date string

Tags: text-processing, sed, date

I am trying to figure out how to reformat a file full of wrongly formatted dates. The source looks like this:

```
{"_id":"","timestamp":"Mon Apr 20 08:30:55 +0000 2015"}
{"_id":"","timestamp":"Mon Apr 20 08:32:25 +0000 2015"}
{"_id":"","timestamp":"Mon Apr 20 08:35:39 +0000 2015"}
```

There are about 3 million entries like this. I need the timestamp to be formatted in the ISO-8601 format, that is:  `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mmm<+/-Offset>`

I have tried this, which works:

```
date -d "Mon Apr 20 08:35:39 +0000 2015" +%FT%T%z
```

Because I am obviously not going to go through all 3 mln entries manually, I looked into using sed for this:

```
cat input.json | sed "s|\"timestamp\":\"\(.*\)\"|\"timestamp\":\"$(date -d \1 +%FT%T%z)\"|g" > output.json
```

However, this prints the same (wrong) output every, namely `2015-05-08T01:00:00+0000`. Is there maybe a brilliant mind somewhere around here who can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be possible to use `sed` for this but `awk` is more natural:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='"'  '$8 {cmd="date -d \""$8"\" +%FT%T%z"; cmd | getline $8; close(cmd)} 1' input.json
{"_id":"","timestamp":"2015-04-20T01:30:55-0700"}
{"_id":"","timestamp":"2015-04-20T01:32:25-0700"}
{"_id":"","timestamp":"2015-04-20T01:35:39-0700"}
```

The above show an offset of -7:00 hours.  This reflects the system's default timezone.  Changing the shell variable `TZ` will change the default.

#### How it works

- `-F'"' -v OFS='"'`

  This sets both the input and output field separators to `"`.
- `$8 {cmd="date -d \""$8"\" +%FT%T%z"; cmd | getline $8; close(cmd)}`

  With `"` as the field separator, the date is field number 8.  This creates string with the correct `date` command and then runs the command capturing the output into an updated field 8.

  The `$8` out in front means that this part will only be run if there is a non-empty value for field 8.  This allows, for example, empty lines to pass through unmolested.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for "print this line."

#### Handling Extra Double-Quotes

Since we are using `"` as the field separator.  Suppose that there are a variable number of `"` before the timestamp.  In that case, we need to refer to the timestamp as the second-last field, `$(NF-1)`, rather than the eighth field, `$8`.  In this case:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='"'  '$8 {cmd="date -d \""$(NF-1)"\" +%FT%T%z"; cmd | getline $(NF-1); close(cmd)} 1' input.json
```

#### Adding Custom Formatting to the Date Field

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='"'  '$8 {cmd="date -d \""$(NF-1)"\" +%FT%T%z"; cmd | getline $(NF-1); close(cmd);$(NF-1)="{$date:" $(NF-1) "}"} 1' input.json
{"_id":"","timestamp":"{$date:2015-04-20T01:30:55-0700}"}
{"_id":"","timestamp":"{$date:2015-04-20T01:32:25-0700}"}
{"_id":"","timestamp":"{$date:2015-04-20T01:35:39-0700}"}
```

Comment: You are great!! One problem though: when the file is just a few entries long (for testing purposes), everything goes smooth. However, when I try to run it on the actual database, I get this error when trying to save the output: ```awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=Apple.json FNR=2407) fatal: cannot open pipe `date -d "Mon Apr 20 08:56:56 +0000 2015" +%FT%T%z' (Too many open files)``` Any thoughts?

Comment: @Diederik Oops.   I updated the answer to add a `close` command.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but one last question. The actual dataset contains more fields, like a text field where people can also use the quote-sign (i.e. `"text":"This is \"great\", really!"`). Is there any way to solve this? Like, is it possible to select only the last " as the separator?

Comment: Using $(NF-1) instead of $8 or any other number does the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: @Diederik  Exactly right!  I just added it to the answer.

Comment: Would you perhaps also know how I can append and prepend to the string?

I just found out that the output file must contain the date in this way: `"timestamp":{$date:"2015-04-20T01:30:55-0700"}`

Obviously this could be done with another command, but given the sheer size of the dataset I'd like to combine it in one :)

Comment: @Diederik OK.  I just added an example that does that.

Comment: Great!!! If I had an Acknowledgements section in my thesis you would certainly be in there. This took my 3/4 hours to figure out!

Answer (score 1):

[`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), [`node`](https://nodejs.org/):

```
cat /tmp/what \
| jq '.timestamp' \
| while read line ; do \
  node -e "console.log(new Date($line).toISOString())" ;\
  done
```

Could also use a single Node.js program to process the whole file for performance, but that might be getting too far into JS-land. (Ping if you want details.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the input is formatted exactly as you have shown,
you can do it entirely in `sed`.  It's a little brute force-ish:

```
sed \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Jan/"timestamp":"01/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Feb/"timestamp":"02/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Mar/"timestamp":"03/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Apr/"timestamp":"04/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... May/"timestamp":"05/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Jun/"timestamp":"06/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Jul/"timestamp":"07/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Aug/"timestamp":"08/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Sep/"timestamp":"09/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Oct/"timestamp":"10/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Nov/"timestamp":"11/' \
        -e 's/"timestamp":"... Dec/"timestamp":"12/' \
-e 's/"timestamp":"\(..\) \(..\) \(..:..:..\) \(.....\) \(....\)"/"timestamp":"\5-\1-\2T\3\4"/' \
        input.json > output.json
```

It replaces the name of the month with its number,
and then it carves up the (now) all-numeric date string,
and puts the pieces back together in the desired order. 
If you want to add `.000` for milliseconds, insert it between `\3` and `\4`.